# Distinct @page margins for printed pages from same html page

Tags: css

Besides the `:left`, `:right`, and `:first` pseudo-classes, Is it possible to specify distinct @page margins for specific sections of an html document?

I have a html doc that is intended to be printed, and all but one "page" requires a margin of 1cm. The other requires a margin of 0.5cm. The position of this section in relation to the others varies, which is why I can't utilize the pseudo-classes I mentioned above, unless I'm missing something. I'd like to be able to specify the print margin for this section independent of the others. Is this possible?

Comment: Does it have any specific attributes? Can you add classes? Is it html?
Some code would be helpful

Comment: Yes to all of those. I can provide code, but since this is more of a general question about the css @page rule, the code would be so generic it wouldn't really add anything to the question.